# Google Maps API Demo - google is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to implement Google Maps API, and have been following the official [Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map#maps_add_map-html).

I've copied the code, and only made a single change:

```
    // Raises an error: Access to script at 'file:///D:/Desktop/Stuff/map-test/test.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>

    // Changed to this
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
```

As a result, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined at initMap
```

I'm guessing it's due to the removal of `type="module"` from the script? How do most implement it as it seems you need to host the module yourself to import it just for this?

I've changed the code to the following, but this throws a warning.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>

// Warning: Google Maps JavaScript API has been loaded directly without a callback. This is not supported and can lead to race conditions and suboptimal performance. For supported loading patterns please see https://goo.gle/js-api-loading
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

I read previous answers on using a HTTP server to host the file, and I misunderstood that they meant hosting the JS file. Instead you should be hosting your HTML files locally for testing instead of directly opening the HTML file (ie double clicking on it in your file explorer).

So using python3:

```
# in the directory that contains index.html:
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

and going to http://localhost:8080/index.html worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: `has been loaded directly without a callback`  add a callback then `&callback=your_callback_function`

Comment: I think your issue is `file:///` ... the world wide web runs on http/https protocol ... a simple http server would probably fix your issue

Comment: You mentioned that you have followed the demo but I can see that the demo looks different from your code.

Comment: @Yrll I only posted the code that I changed from the demo, I copy and pasted the rest directly from the demo

Comment: @JaromandaX I get it now, I read previous answers on using a HTTP server to host the file, and I misunderstood that they meant hosting the JS file. Edited the question with the solution.

Comment: if you have a solution, add an Answer, don't edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I read previous answers on using a HTTP server to host the file, and I misunderstood that they meant hosting the JS file. Instead you should be hosting your HTML files locally for testing instead of directly opening the HTML file (ie double clicking on it in your file explorer).

So using python3:

```
# in the directory that contains index.html:
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

and going to http://localhost:8080/index.html worked for me. Thanks!